# Is it possible to pass a MySQL record 'id' from tab to tab in a tabbed form?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure how to explain this clearly so here is the link to what I am trying to do

[demo](http://auniqueconstruction.com/temp/customer_contact.php)

Basically you get to this form from a MySQL search results page, you click on a record and it sends you to this page and passes the record id in the borswer. So clicking on row 20 will pass ?id=20 in the browser and display in the first tab all that customer info that's called for on that form.

What I want to do is to be able to click on a tab and view the rest of that same customers info that is called for in each of the different tabs.

Right now all I can do is view the info in the first tab, if I move to a new tab nothing is there obviously because the id doesn't pass.

How can I pass the id from tab to tab? I've got session_start(); at the top of every page but that doesn't seem to be doing anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as a get parameter in the URL, so that your id is always referenced in the URL of each tab in the section.  Each tab will pass the id on to the other tabs, as follows:

Your search results would then link to, e.g.: customer_contact.php?id=123

And your tabs would each grab the id like this:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_GET['id'])) header('Location: /error_page.php');
    $id = $_GET['id'];
 ?>
```

And link to each other as follows:

```
<a href="customer_system.php?id=<?=$id?>" class=" topitem">
```